# Response.body() returns null using nodejs with retrofit android

Tags: java, android, node.js, retrofit

I am using nodejs with android application using retrofit.

I have some problem in get method.

```
login.js //Nodejs code

response.redirect("/details?vv="+ajx); //ajx contains the regno that means it contains 101

app.get('/details',(request, response) => 
{
    var ajx2=request.query.vv;
    var sql2 = "select * from student where regno='"+ajx2+"'";
                    connection.query(sql2, function (err, gk) 
                    {
                    if(gk.length > 0)
                    {   
                    Object.keys(gk).forEach(function(key){
                        var rea=gk[key];
                        const objToSend={
                            reg1:rea.regno,
                            name1:rea.s_name
                        }
                        response.status(300).send(JSON.stringify(objToSend))
                        console.log("True");
                        console.log(objToSend);
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    response.status(600).send() 
                    }
                    });
});
```

In my console its working fine.
True
{ reg1: '101', name1: 'XYZ' }

But In android studio the response.body() is not working its returns null.

```
RetrofitInterface.java

@GET("/details")
    Call<LoginResult> getLog(@Query("vv") String vv);
```

```
LoginResult.java

package com.example.nodue;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LoginResult
{
 @SerializedName("reg1")
    @Expose
    private String reg1;

    public String getReg1()
    {
        return reg1;
    }
    public void setReg1(String reg1)
    {
        this.reg1=reg1;
    }
}

I am also tried without @SerializedName() and @Expose but its not working..
Only getter,setter its not working
```

```
ThirdActivity.java

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RetrofitInterface request=retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Call<LoginResult> call=request.getLog(vv);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResult> call, Response<LoginResult> response) {
                if(response.code()==300)
                {
                    LoginResult aji=response.body();  // its returns null..
                    Log.d("hh","Hwllo");
                    System.out.println(aji);
                    //listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,go));
                    Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this,aji.getReg1(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResult> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I am using the same method to get the list of details using `List<LoginResult> aji=response.body`, Here i can fetch multiple rows its working fine. So the same method i have to use to fetch single row without list i am using `LoginResult aji=response.body()` but its returns null...Please help me..